# Want a javascript function to run every minute, but max 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax javascript method that pulls data from a page etc.

I want this process to run on a timed interval, say every minute.
But I don't want it to loop forever, so max out at 3 times.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: quick and dirty, but why not just have a counter increment every time the request is run and if(counter < 3){ intervalRun();}?

Comment: @optimate: What is intervalRun()?

Comment: He meant to say `setInterval`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Like this:

```
var runCount = 0;    
function timerMethod() {
    runCount++;
    if(runCount > 3) clearInterval(timerId);

    //...
}

var timerId = setInterval(timerMethod, 60000);    //60,000 milliseconds
```

Comment: +1 - this is the better solution.  With `setInterval()` you avoid continously calling `setTimeout()` over and over, and the looped timing of `foo()` is slightly faster because you don't have to wait for `foo()` to process everything before setting up the next call.

Comment: @zombat Actually, setTimeout() is often preferred in a lot of scenarios to setInterval(), mostly because setInterval() will call the function 60 seconds after the first function *started running*, not finished.  Especially now that Chrome & Firefox are limiting background tabs, setInterval() is much more reliable if you don't want to stack up all three of those function calls at once.

Answer (score 12):

A closure-based solution, using `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`:

```
// define a generic repeater
var repeater = function(func, times, interval) {
  var ID = window.setInterval( function(times) {
    return function() {
      if (--times <= 0) window.clearInterval(ID);
      func();
    }
  }(times), interval);
};

// call the repeater with a function as the argument
repeater(function() {
  alert("stuff happens!");
}, 3, 60000);
```

EDIT: Another way of expressing the same, using `setTimeout()` instead:

```
var repeater = function(func, times, interval) {
  window.setTimeout( function(times) {
    return function() {
      if (--times > 0) window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
      func();
    }
  }(times), interval);
};

repeater(function() {
  alert("stuff happens!");
}, 3, 2000);
```

Maybe the latter is a bit easier to understand.

In the `setTimeout()` version you can ensure that the next iteration happens only *after* the previous one has finished running. You'd simply move the `func()` line *above* the `setTimeout()` line.

Comment: +1 I like your closure-based solution better than my object property based one below.  At least we were both thinking in terms of re -usability :D

Answer (score 4):

A reusable approach

```
function setMaxExeuctionInterval( callback, delay, maxExecutions )
{
  var intervalCallback = function()
  {
    var self = intervalCallback;
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof self.executedIntervals )
    {
      self.executedIntervals = 1;
    }
    if ( self.executedIntervals == maxExecutions )
    {
      clearInterval( self.interval )
    }
    self.executedIntervals += 1;
    callback();
  };
  intervalCallback.interval = setInterval( intervalCallback, delay );
}

// console.log requires Firebug
setMaxExeuctionInterval( function(){ console.log( 'hi' );}, 700, 3 );
setMaxExeuctionInterval( function(){ console.log( 'bye' );}, 200, 8 );
```

Answer (score 4):

This anonymous function (it doesn't introduce any new globals) will do what you need. All you have to do is replace `yourFunction` with your function.

```
(function(fn, interval, maxIterations) {
    var iterations = 0,
    id = setInterval(function() {
        if (++iterations > maxIterations)
            return clearInterval(id);

        fn();
    }, interval);
})(yourFunction, 60000, 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do with setInterval

```
var count = 0;

var interval = setInterval(yourFunction(), 1000);

function yourFunction (){

  clearInterval(interval);  
  if(count < 3){

    count ++;
    interval = setInterval(yourFunction(), 1000);
  }

// your code


}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Answer (score 3):

To extend [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245617/want-a-javascript-function-to-run-every-minute-but-max-3-times/1245737#1245737) function:

If you want to know how many cycles are left:

```
var repeater = function(func, times, interval) {
    window.setTimeout( function(times) {
    return function() {
      if (--times > 0) window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
      func(times);
    }
  }(times), interval);
}
```

and use:

```
repeater(function(left){
    //... (do you stuff here) ...
    if(left == 0) {
        alert("I'm done");
    }
}, 3, 60000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use setInterval, be sure to get a reference.

```
var X=setInterval(....);
```

Also, have a global counter

```
var c=0;
```

Inside the function called by the setIntervale do:

```
c++;
if(c>3) window.clearInterval(X);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval() and then inside the called function keep a count of how many times you've run the function and then clearInterval().

Or you can use setTimeout() and then inside the called function call setTimeout() again until you've done it 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
var testTimeInt = 3;
function testTime(){

    testTimeInt--;

    if(testTimeInt>0)
       setTimeOut("testTime()", 1000);

}


setTimeOut("testTime()", 1000);
```